# dplyr count, sum and calculate the percentage and round to whole number using R

Tags: r, dplyr, count, sum, product

I kindly request for help in grouping by ID, counting non-zeros and presenting the results as the percentage of the total in that particular ID
My data

```
library(dplyr)
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
x<-c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
df1<-data.frame(id,x)
head(df1)
```

in my results, after grouping by id=1, then i need column with total for ones as 2 and another column with the precentage (2/5)= 40. For group id=2 then i need the total for the column as 1 and percentage as (1/4)=25

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(sum_of_1 = sum(x!=0),
            pct= round((sum_of_1/n())*100))
```

This one works. Thanks for the help Hulk

Comment: Delighted to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(sum_of_1       = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE),
            pct            = round((sum_of_1/n())*100))
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works well. but suppose my x<-c(0,7,0,8,0,0,0,3,0), and i want the same results as the code you have provided above?

Comment: It is up to you what you want to accomplish with x<-c(0,7,0,8,0,0,0,3,0). I consider x<-c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0) a binary variable and so percentage make sense. But if you use x<-c(0,7,0,8,0,0,0,3,0), then you should think about other ways of summarization. For example, you can consider calculating mean/median Or dichotomize that into "0" and "more than 0" and calculate % again.
As I said, it's totally upto your needs.

Comment: Thankyou hulk. what I meant is this. x<-c(0,7,0,8,0,0,0,3,0), whereby x is the distance to a health facility, whereby 0 means the facility is within reach and 7means the facility is 7km away. now my question is, how can i know the number of people who walk to the facility in a given county as a percentage of the total people in the county? county_id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2) ,x<-c(0,7,0,8,0,0,0,3,0)